# Fixed elements are vibrating in Google Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome

I encountered a minor issue with position:fixed applied to divs in Google Chrome. When I would start scrolling, the fixed div would start vibrating.

The issue is illustrated in this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r09Lakes/). Make sure to open it in google chrome!!! I know the issue does not exist in MS Edge, but haven't tried it in other browsers.

I think the cause of this issue has to do with the way Google Chrome handles position: fixed. But the question(s) I have is:

**How do I prevent this vibrating effect in Google Chrome?**

***html***

```
<div id="header"></div>
<div class="longdiv"></div>
```

***css***

```
#header{
  position: fixed;
  height: 100px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  background-color: black;
}
.longdiv{
  height: 1000px;
}
```

PS: I am using version: 52.0.2743.116 (Official Build) m (32-bit)

Comment: Not seeing anything in Chrome Version 53.0.2785.46 beta-m (64-bit)

Comment: What version of chrome are you using ? I dont see any with 51.0.2704.106 m

Comment: dont see it 52.0.2743.116 m

Comment: Might be as simple as switch it off and on again

Comment: I've got the Canary, v 54.0.2823.0 (64 bit) and I don't see it. It's fine in the other browsers too (Mozilla, IE11).

Comment: I can't see vibrations on Google Chrome 52.0.2743.116 m (64-bit)

Comment: Someone ought to test it with a 32 bit version I presume.

Comment: Hmm could it possibly be caused by running 32-bit Google Chrome in a 64-bit OS (windows)? It's good to know that it apparently isn't a major issue in general anyway.

Comment: 52.0.2743.116 m (32 bit) on 64 bit OS (Windows 10). If you know what to look for you can sometimes see a *very* slight movement in the fixed element when scrolling. But even when looking for it it is so barely noticeable one might think it is just an illusion...